# Reshape tensor with dimension 1 to [-1, 0]

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I currently try to train my neural network with Cross Entropy Loss. However for that to work I need my target to have the dimension [-1, 0] but I can't reshape it so the grad_fn= doesn't get deleted

```
pred = self.model(states[idx])
```

This gives out something like this:

```
tensor([0.1562, 0.1401, 0.1713, 0.1283, 0.1331, 0.1461, 0.1250],
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

But this should have the shape [-1, 0].
Thanks for any help.

Comment: shape `[-1, 0]` is meaningless - it means an empty tensor. is it possible you mean `shape=[-1, 1]`?

Comment: Uhm so this is the error that I get:
    ret = input.log_softmax(dim)
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Comment: your problem is not the shape, but the `dim` value, you have a 1-dimensional vector (`dim=1`) and it seems like your `dim` argument for the loss function is `dim=1` which means computing the loss along the second dimension that does not exist. It seems like you collapse your batch dimension somewhere along the way. don't do that.